# Guardar pdf en App. De un JSON con el base64. Cordova Phonegap File o File transfer. writer.truncate(11) writer.seek(4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

Hola tengo una duda acerca de como convertir un base64 a pdf con jquery o javascript.

Y también que son los números que se pasan por parámetro a la las funciones => `writer.truncate(11)`  `writer.seek(4)` y en el caso que quiera guardar un pdf como debería hacerlo.

Este es mi códiogo actual

```
json = { DocArchivoB64:"JVBERi0xLj.......=" //base64
DocArchivoNombre:"CARTA.pdf"
DocCodigo:1
DocEmpresa:null
DocFecha:"2018-06-22T13:00:00"
DocObservacion:""
}
```

1. ¿Como Convertir base64 a pdf?
   Es correcto? El teléfono da mensaje de error al abrir.
2. En la función `gotFileWriter(writer)` que son para que son los números que se pasan como parámetros  `writer.truncate(11)`  `writer.seek(4)`

   ```
   function base64Tobinaty(jsonMasImg) {
       var base64str = jsonMasImg.DocArchivoB64;

       var binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
       var len = binary.length;
       var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
       var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
       for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
       }
       // create the blob object with content-type "application/pdf"               
       var blob = new Blob([view], {type: "application/pdf"});
       var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       return blob;
   }


   var documentoDescargado = null;

   function descargarDocumento(jsonMasImg) {
       documentoDescargado = jsonMasImg; // obtengo un objeto binario y
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
   }

   function gotFS(fileSystem) {
       var nombreDoc = documentoDescargado.DocArchivoNombre;
       alert(nombreDoc);
       fileSystem.root.getFile( nombreDoc, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);

   }

   function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
       fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
   }

   function gotFileWriter(writer) {
       var pdf =  base64Tobinaty(documentoDescargado);

       writer.onwriteend = function (evt) { writer.truncate(); writer.onwriteend = function (evt) { writer.seek(); writer.write( ); writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {}; }; };
       alert("paso el onwriteend");
       writer.write(pdf);
   }

   function fail(error) {
       alert(error.code);
   }
   ```

Gracias a todos por compartir sus opiniones mejoras o sugerencias.

**SOLUCIONADO !! Código correcto.** Hola Lectores a pesar de no saber para que o como funciona writer.truncate(11) writer.seek(4) quiero informar que el código que coloque arriba anda a la perfección. De todos medos si alguien me puede explicar estos dos métodos seria un gran aporte. Ya que al quitar el 11 y el 4 quedo funcionando. Aclaración a esto le falta mostrar un aviso de que ha sido guardado o abrir la ubicación del archivo.

Comment: **SOLUCIONADO !! Código correcto.** Hola Lectores a pesar de no saber para que o como funciona **writer.truncate(11)  writer.seek(4)** quiero informar que el código que coloque arriba anda a la perfección. De todos medos si alguien me puede explicar estos dos métodos seria un gran aporte. Ya que al quitar el 11 y el 4 quedo funcionando. **Aclaración** a esto le falta mostrar un aviso de que ha sido guardado o abrir la ubicación del archivo.

Comment: Hola Juan si quieres agregar un comentario adicional a tu pregunta, hazlo haciendo click en el enlace editar que se encuentra bajo ella. Te invito a leer el [tour] y [ask]